# Building Qt 5.4.0 on win7-64bit msvc2010 and failed everytime

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt

I download qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.4.0.zip and jom_1_0_14.zip 
and install ActivePerl, python2.7.9, ruby 2.1.5 from Qt website
also download icu and unpack to c:\icu

I'm trying to build Qt 5.4.0 by following command

```
c:\Qt\5.4.0>configure -prefix %CD%\qtbase -debug-and-release -icu -I c:\icu\include -L c:\icu\lib64 -opensource -platform win32-msvc2010
```

and failed everytime

here's some error message

```
c:\qt\5.4.0\qtbase\src\corelib\tools\qcollator_p.h(52) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'unicode/ucol.h': No such file or directory
c:\qt\5.4.0\qtbase\src\corelib\tools\qtimezoneprivate_p.h(53) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'unicode/ucal.h': No such file or directory
tools\qlocale_icu.cpp(40) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'unicode/uloc.h': No such file or directory
c:\qt\5.4.0\qtbase\src\corelib\tools\qcollator_p.h(52) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'unicode/ucol.h': No such file or directory
jom: C:\Qt\5.4.0\qtbase\src\corelib\Makefile.Debug [.obj\debug\qtextboundaryfinder.obj] Error 2

jom: C:\Qt\5.4.0\qtbase\src\corelib\Makefile [debug-all] Error 2
jom: C:\Qt\5.4.0\qtbase\src\Makefile [sub-corelib-make_first] Error 2
jom: C:\Qt\5.4.0\qtbase\Makefile [sub-src-make_first] Error 2
jom: C:\Qt\5.4.0\Makefile [module-qtbase-make_first] Error 2
```

I know window sdk 7.1 had some bug and might cause this, so I followed the following steps

1. uninstall visual studio 2010 x86/x64 redistribute
2. install window sdk v7.1
3. install visual studio 2010 x86/x64 redistribute
4. repair visual studio 2010 sp1

and then using "visual studio x64 win64 command prompt" to used these command

```
c:\Qt\5.4.0>configure -prefix %CD%\qtbase -debug-and-release -icu -I c:\icu\include -L c:\icu\lib64 -opensource -platform win32-msvc2010
c:\Qt\jom\jom.exe -j 10
```

I also download qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.1.0 and had same problem, so I think there must be something needs to be done but ain't done.
Can anyone give me some help or advice , thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
Cannot open include file: 'unicode/ucol.h': No such file or directory
```

This suggests that it cannot find the ICU headers.

I'd recommend to first make sure make sure that the path to the ICU include directory is right. If the problem persists, try build without ICU.

Comment: thank you for your answering!
ucol.h and ucal.h were in c:\icu\include document, and i added "c:\icu\include" to include path, so i don't know why it couldn't find  these headers.
I need to use some libraries which is based on icu, but i'll try build without icu.
thnaks again!

Comment: The compiler expects "ucol.h" and "ucal.h" to be at "C:\icu\include\unicode\ucol.h" and "C:\icu\include\unicode\ucal.h", not at "C:\icu\include\ucol.h" and "C:\icu\include\ucol.h", when you add "c:\icu\include" to the include path.

Answer (score -1):

From [the Qt website](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-requirements.html):

> On Windows, they need to be manually installed and the "include" and
>   "lib"  folders of the ICU installation must be appended to the INCLUDE
>   and LIB  environment variables after calling the Windows SDK setup
>   script.  The "bin" folder of the ICU installation should be appended
>   to the PATH  environment variable in order to for the DLLs to be found
>   at run-time.